# difficulty in implementing classes in different file(linker error)

Tags: class, header, linker

please help guys i m getting a "linker error(undefined reference to burito::burito())
 I M NOT ABLE TO IMPLEMENT CLASSES IN DIFFERENT FILES

***burito.cpp file***

```
#include<iostream>
#include "burito.h"

using namespace std;

burito::burito()
{
 cout<<"hello everybody";
}
```

***burito.h file***

```
#ifndef BURITO_H
#define BURITO_H
class burito
{
    public:
        burito();


};

#endif
```

***class_test.cpp file***

```
#include<iostream>
#include "burito.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    burito bo;


return 0;
system("PAUSE");







}
```